# Safe parameter definition with JDBI

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jdbi

I am finding myself in need of the templating engine included in JDBI (3). The reason I seem to need it is because I have statements that span multiple databases (on the same server, through the same connection), and those database names need to come from user input.

I am apropriately terrified of handing user input in any way, shape or form to the database other than through bound parameters. As I understand the templating implementation, it by necessity forgoes that protections that bound parameters provide.

I worry that naive protections against malicious input such as `if (dbName.contains(...` or `dbName.replaceAll(...` are inadequate at best.

I suppose I have two questions: is this the apropriate way to go about this, and if so, what steps can and should I take to minimize the attack vector that using templating in conjunction with user input opens ?

Comment: A bind variable can be used for a *value*, not for a table or schema name (database name in MySQL). You must implement a check of the parameter against the existing objects in the DB and than generate a dynamic SQL.

Comment: I am talking about argument binding through the JDBI templating engine, not SQL variable binding. The JDBI templating engine manipulates raw SQL and thus does exactly what you suggest. But checking against existing objects is definitely a suggestion I will implement that should cut down considerably on possible malicious values, thank you.